# Why shake doesn't work when the screen is off on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, shake

I am playing an audio file in the app, so it doesn't turn off when the phone is locked and the screen is off.
However when I want detect shake it does not work.

It works fine when the app is open and when the screen is locked (not off). The app is definitely running because the logs are working fine.

Any idea?

I use the following code:

```
-(BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder {
    //make it respond to shake events
    return YES;
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    //make it respond to shake events
    [self becomeFirstResponder];
}

- (void)motionEnded:(UIEventSubtype)motion withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    if (event.type == UIEventSubtypeMotionShake) {
        NSLog(@"Shake detected");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would help you.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setIdleTimerDisabled:YES];
```

This wont let the screen turn off.

Hope this helps.

**EDIT:**

But Even I feel the same as Akshay does. That it is not possible to capture UIEvent when screen is off.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know that and I already use it, but I want to make it work when the screen is off as well.

Comment: @Tibidabo: Check EDIT section of my answer

Comment: The funny thing is it works when it is locked as long as the screen is not off. So if I press the power button to turn it off it stops working, when I press it again, which brings up the lock screen, it starts working again. I guess it must be some sort of power saving feature was you all said, I was just hoping I missed something.

Comment: I was hoping for a solution, but at least I didn't have to spend hours to figure out it's not possible. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Monitoring the accelerometer causes extra power consumption by the phone, so it is disabled while the phone is locked. I don't believe there is a way around this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can capture `UIEvents` when the screen is off.